# What would be a good way to combine data from two sources in a service?

Tags: angular, rxjs

So I have this problem I have been trying to wrap my head around: I have this array of sidebar items that I need to merge from two sources. First source would be in the front-end code base and it pertains to visual aspects of the items: icon class, url, etc. that we will be maintaining with the front-end code base. The second source would be the database, as I need to keep some information there in order to provide a feature where any one of these items could be marked as completed and their state should persist.

The items look like this:

```
export interface Item {
    id?: number;
    name: string;
    label: string;
    completed?: boolean;
    iconClass: string;
    url: string;
}
```

I maintain label, iconClass and url on the front-end and I get id and completed from the database, and I "join" them by name, which is present in both sources.

And here is a snippet of my service:

```
export class SidebarService {

    someNecessaryId: number;
    // I keep the front-end related items here for the moment
    items: Item[] = [...];

    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient
    ) { }

    async init() {
        const url = `${baseUrl}/${this.someNecessaryId}/sidebar-items`;
        const itemsDb = await this.http.get(url).toPromise();

        if (itemsDb instanceof Array && itemsDb.length) {
            // Here I basically merge the two sources together
            this.items = this.items.map(item => {
                const found = itemsDb.filter(itemDb => itemDb.name === item.name)[0];
                return {...item, ...found};
            });
        }
    }

    mark(item: Item) {
       const actualItem = this.items.filter(fItem => fItem.name === item.name)[0];
       const url = `${baseUrl}/${this.someNecessaryId}/sidebar-items/${item.id}/mark`;
       this.http.post(url, item)
         .subscribe(res => {
           if (res instanceof Item) {
              actualItem.completed = res.completed;
           }
       });
    }
}
```

After toying with this service in the component, subscribing to the results and noticing all kinds of problems, I decided to try async await so I know all the information is available straight away in the component. Is this a good choice?

EDIT: I might have left some important details out. To paint the bigger picture:

- I am using a directive (attached to a button somewhere) that marks these items as completed or vice-versa. The merged information needs to be available here. I chose a directive because I need this same logic in multiple places;
- I need the merged information when marking in the service, as I need the id to be present on the item when sending the request to the backend;
- In the components themselves, I identify the current item based on the url (because of the fact that, on a refresh, params that were otherwise propagated by navigating to an item - clicking on it - would not be available).

So far, the only viable alternative I see is to use an APP_INITIALIZER to be certain the entirety of the information is available in all these places.

LATER EDIT: I need some form of single source of truth for these items for them to update their state based on the mark / unmark, as far as I can tell with my limited knowledge. So far, only using async + await does that.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend to use Observables here async/await is also waiting but makes your code readable.

Also you can make items in your code that you keep locally as a map so reads are faster and you can fetch them with key/value pair of key as name of the item and value as the items value. {`{name: {item} }`}

You can use the async pipe to directly bind the observable to the template as shown below

```
export class SidebarService {

  someNecessaryId: number;
  // I keep the front-end related items here for the moment
  itemsMap: { [key: tsring]: Item } = {}; // keep an Hashmap or object dictionary for faster reads
  items$: Observable<Item[]>;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  async init() {
    const url = `${baseUrl}/${this.someNecessaryId}/sidebar-items`;
    this.items$ = this.http.get(url)
      .pipe(
        map(response => response.map(item => ({
          ...item, ...(this.itemsMap[item.name] || {})
        })))
      );
  }

  getItems () {
    return this.items$;
  }

}
```

From a template

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items$ | async">
  <!-- do something with item in this for loop -->
```

From a (directive/component).ts

```
items = [];
constructor (private service: SidebarService) {
  this.service.init();
}
getData() {
  this.service.getItems().subscribe(items => {
    this.items = items;
  })
}
```

Comment: I like this example as it is elegant, but it does not suit my needs. I somehow need to merge the items and have them available for use in multiple places: components, templates and a directive that I am using.

Comment: yes why not use it from here?? added a function which you can call from any component directive or anywhere

Comment: I did not downvote your answer, if that's what you think. I do not have sufficient reputation for that. When I have sufficient reputation I will give you 2 upvotes, sir :)) Cheers and thanks

Comment: I tried your example and, although it is nice to work with, it sadly does not update the items in the template (where  I use the async pipe). So basically I need to add a badge for the completed items and it does not update when I update the items,, or I am doing something wrong. Going to have to go with the async await example. Thanks!

Comment: It is not updating because you never called init function on template.

Comment: I actually did. I think for this to work, I would also need to use a store and get the items from there.

Comment: if you are using this get items can you try making it static see if it works

Comment: I guess I got it from OP.  I asked him if this method was called or not. He said it was called